# Continuous functions from real numbers to discrete space

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

One of my homework problems is this:
"Let X = $\mathbb{R} \!\,$ with the usual metric and let X′ be a discrete metric space. Describe all continuous functions from X to X′."

A function f : X $\rightarrow$ X' is continuous if for all $\epsilon$>0, there exists a $\delta$>0 s.t. for all x,y $\in \!\,$X, if d(x,y)

The most common discrete metric we discuss is this:

d(x,y) = 0 if x=y &

d(x,y) = 1 if x$\ne$y

My two ideas for continuous functions f : X $\rightarrow$ X' are:

1) f(x) = k where k is a constant

2) f(x) = [x]

My reasoning is that both of these functions take two values x,y in $\mathbb{R} \!\,$ and return f(x) and f(y) s.t. f(x)=f(y), so the discrete metric has distance of 0. For 1, this is true for all x,y. For 2, this is true for d(x,y) < min {d(x,1/2), d(y,1/2)}.

Do both of these work? Are there any more such functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint : discrete metric is totally disconnected. but $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.

Do you know this result : Continuous image of a connected set is connected?

Comment: We are not being introduced to connectedness until the next section.

Comment: then it is right time to see the definition of connectedness. You want to prove using the definition of continuous functions?

Comment: This exercise follows immediately after this theorem: `"A function f : X → X′ is continuous iff for any open set V ⊂ X′, the set f_inverse(V) is an open set in X"`, this corollary: `"Suppose that (X, d), (X′, d′), and (X′′, d′′) are metric spaces, and f : X → X′ and g : X′→ X′′ are continuous. Then g ◦ f : X → X′′ is continuous"`, and this exercise, which I have already done: `"Let X and X′ be metric spaces and assume that X has the discrete metric. Show that any function f : X → X′ is continuous."` I'd like to do my problem by using these 3 results and the defn. of continuity, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since *everything* is open in $\;X'\;$ , the inverse image of everything in $\;X\;$ must be open.

Check now that if there exist $\;x,y\in X\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)\neq f(y)\;$, then since $\;U:=\{f(x),f(y)\}\subset X'\;$ is open, so must be $\;f^{-1}(U)\subset X\;$, and you surely know what are the open set in $\;\Bbb R\;$ with the usual topology...get a contradiction.

Comment: Why is "Since everything is open in X′ , the inverse image of everything in X must be open," true? The definition of an inverse image is apparently f_inverse[U] = {x belongs to X | f(x) belongs to U}. I don't see the immediate connection.

Comment: **If** the function $\;f:X\to X"\;$ is *continuous*, then $\;f^{-1}(U)\;$ (yes, the definition of "inverse image" is what you wrote) **must** be open for *any* open $\;U\subset X'\;$, and since **any** subset in $\;X'\;$ is open then the inverse image of *anything* must be open in $\;X=\Bbb R\;$ with the usual Euclidean topology...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand this proof. I will just have to see what the feedback on the homework says.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hi, any chance  you can elaborate what is the contradiction ? we have $f(a,b) = U$ , i don't see what's wrong

Comment: @Liad Well, this was a looooong time ago, but the arguments are simple: if $\;f(x)=a\neq b=f(y)\;$ , and since $\;U:=\{\,a,\,b\,\}\subset X'\;$ is open (as **everything's** open in a discrete space!) , then it must be that $\;f^{-1}(U)\subset X\;$ is open *if* $\;f\;$ *is continuous* . Yet the only *open* subsets in $\;X=\Bbb R\;$ (the real line with the usual topology) are the unions of open intervals (and then use the Intermediate Value Theorem)...Of course, connectedness can also be used as $\;X'\;$ is totally disconnected, as the other answer mentions.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks , indeed it was a long time ago :). 
i understand that everything is open in $X'$ , but $f:R \to X'$ , so we have that the image of union of open intervals is $U = \{f(x) , f(y) \}$ for $f(x) \ne f(y)$. how can i use intermediate value theorem?  the image of $f$ is not contained in $R$ (im new to topo. so im not familiar with disconnected term)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you: how come the image of $\;f\;$ is not contained in $\;\Bbb R\;$ ? It is contained in $\;X'\subset\Bbb R\;$, with the discrete topology... And, in fact, I think that, in the last analysis, to continue with this proof I would need to use in some form connectedness, as in the other answer but in a way much messier trajectory...

Comment: @DonAntonio $X'$ is a discrete metric space - who said it is contained in $R$ ? (sorry for all the questions .. im trying to understand this)

Comment: @DonAntonio btw, the hint i have in my exercise is to show $R$ is a union of 2 distinct open interval in the case $f$ is not constant.

Comment: @Liad Oh, now I see....I thought $\;X'\;$ was $\;\Bbb R\;$ itself with the discrete topology. Please disregard my commentaries with this...hehe. Indeed, too long a time has ellapsed...Anyway, using your hint: suppose $\;f\;$ isn't constant and etc., as before. Put $\;U:=\{x\in X\;/\;f(x)=a\in X'\}\;,\;\;V:=\{x\in X\;/\;f(x)\neq a\}\;$ . By assumption, $\;U,V\;$ are open and non-empty, and $\;\Bbb R=f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V)\;$ , with $\;f{-1}(U),\,f^{-1}(V)\;$ *also disjoint* and open . This cannot be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55714/discussion-between-liad-and-donantonio).